# Defining standalone functions inside a header file - C++

Tags: c++, function, linker-errors, header-files

When implementing a standalone function inside a header file, it gives an error "Error  4   fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found" whereas standalone template functions and member functions of a class work fine when implemented inside a header file.

Is the normal standalone function needed to be defined as an inline function? can anybody give me a clear explanation why?

Comment: Member functions don't (without being inlined) unless they're defined inside the class definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you include it - it gets redefined into that object file

an inline function allows this because it isn't a linker object

Comment: It's polite to click the tick next to the answer to show your appreciation.

Comment: @HajananthNallaivarothayan Are you missing proper include guards for your header files??

Comment: @HajananthNallaivarothayan Hmm.... using `inline` shouldn't really matter or make a significant difference, it's just a hint for the compiler. Your problems seem to lurk elsewhere (at least from a portability POV).

Comment: @g-makulik from the standard: `Every program shall contain exactly one definition of every non-inline function or variable that is odr-used
in that program; no diagnostic required. The definition can appear explicitly in the program, it can be found in the standard or a user-defined library, or (when appropriate) it is implicitly defined (see 12.1, 12.4 and 12.8). An inline function shall be defined in every translation unit in which it is odr-used.`

Comment: @GlennTeitelbaum Yup! But this shouldn't bother the linker at all! If there are equivalent `inline` signatures and definitions are seen by the linker it shouldn't complain about _'multiply defined symbols'_!!

Comment: @ g-makulik, I didn't use the inline keyword and also implicitly ended up with multiple inclusions of a same header file